# Hashed and salted passwords are saved as random symbols in SQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, .net

Hashed and salted password look like this in the database:

[image]

Is this how it is supposed to be? Because the hash and salt that i get in the backend look like this:

[image]

Comment: It's possible that it's just being read in a different character set.  Does the application still work as expected?  Are the hashed passwords still usable?

Comment: Why are you storing them as text? You should store the hash and salt as raw bytes (`binary` type)

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that you are using different encodings